# How can I index document in druid using unix timestamp in seconds

Tags: druid

I am trying to use unix timestamp in seconds in timestampspec. But I am confused what to use in the format. I have tried auto option and millis but both doesn't yields expected results.

```
{
  "format":"millis",
  "column":"eventTime"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use posix time is the Unix timestamp in seconds

```
  "timestampSpec" : {
    "column" : "timestamp",
    "format" : "posix"
  },
```

Please go through various formats here
http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html

Comment: Let me try out that one. Thanks for your quick reply.